# HTC Trophy/Outlook: I stopped getting notified when I receive emails in all non-Inbox folders

Tags: sync, outlook, htc

On my work laptop, I have several rules set up to move certain emails to specific folders as they arrive in my inbox (ELMAH errors from our ASP.NET web app if you want to know). I am assuming these rules are all saved on the Exchange server because I can browse synced folders through Outlook on my Windows 7 phone and see that they've been moved to the proper folders.

I used to be notified by my phone of all incoming emails even if a rule moved them to another folder so long as I've synced that folder. A few months ago, however, it stopped notifying me of all emails unless the email went to my inbox. If a rule moves the email to another synced folder, the only way I know about it is if I periodically check the folders manually to see if they contain any new emails.

This is bad since I need to be notified of application errors on my phone as they come in. I do not want to disable the rule and have these emails go to my inbox because I do not want them going there. Can anyone explain why this has only recently happened, why it worked before and why it doesn't work now? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification on the live tile is only for the folder that is pinned -- by default this is *just* the inbox, but you can browse to a folder (such as your application errors), and then, if you pull up the menu from the bottom of the screen, you can choose to pin *that folder* to the start menu, and it will show the number of messages received since you last viewed that folder.

Comment: But I never had my Errors folder pinned before.  This issue just started occurring.  Maybe a phone update somehow patched that.  I'll try your solution later when I am in an area where I have coverage.

Comment: I've never known the notification to include sub folders for Exchange mailboxes, so it may well be an old update that changed the behaviour subtly (possibly with Windows Phone 7.5 which introduced secondary tiles). If anything though, this new behaviour is possibly more useful for you, as you can focus on just those you need to.

Comment: So I tried your suggestion and it worked.  I am now getting notifications.  However, the folder that I pinned has subfolders and I am getting notifications for those.  Without redoing my folder structure, is there a way to get notifications only for the parent folder and not its child folders?

Comment: You answered my question, so you get the answer.  I guess it's not too painful that I need to move my "Critical Errors" folder to the root.  I just wish I didn't have to do that.